# How to set up PhoneGap on windows

Tags: windows, mobile, cordova, cmd

I'm trying to install PhoneGap on my Windows for a school project and my attempts to install and get a test application up and running have been unsuccessful.  I installed node.js, and  here are my EXACT commands that followed which I ran in the command prompt:

```
cd C:/ProgramFiles/nodejs
npm install -g phonegap
```

Phonegap went to work extracting a bunch of directories and doing a bunch of work which was, to my knowledge, successful.

I have a simple test file, Test.html, detailed below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC 
"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>"Test Application"</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is a Test Application!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The directory of this file is C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/PhoneGapApp

So then, following the example on phonegap.com, I did the following:

```
cd C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/PhoneGapApp
phonegap create AppDirectory AppName
```

And the second line blew up with the details that the "phonegap" command couldn't be found.  Not really shocking but I don't know how to fix it.

So can anyone give me a thorough, detailed explanation about what to do next and how to get a test application running?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you installed phonegap using npm, you included the `-g` flag - this tells npm to install the cordova package "globally", so that it is available from anywhere on your computer.

However, since the `phonegap` command failed, somehow this obviously didn't work. I'm guessing that you probably don't have the npm directory on your PATH.

Try to add this to your PATH environment variable:

`;C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming\npm`
The semicolon is there to separate the directories, make sure the npm folder actually exists at this location.

(If you are using a mac machine, this path will be different - I'm not sure where npm will et installed.)

Comment: You can test that node and npm are installed correctly by opening up `cmd` and running `node --version` and `npm --version`. They should both output version stuff, no matter which directory you are in.